# Can i submit visa application for Canada , without Invitation Letter?

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas

Like the subject states, Has anyone tried something like this to IRCC before? just need some form of Clarification and stuff.

**Edits**

I am applying for a Tourist visa. Just Visit and come back home, Want to make Canada my second home.

Comment: What kind of visa are you applying for? And what are you wanting to do in Canada? Please edit the information into the question.

Comment: Have you read https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/about-visitor-visa.html It covers everything you need to know

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the information is readily available on the Government of Canada website

Comment: close what? where does it state the question I asked? i dont see anything like that here

Comment: "Just a visit" and "I want to make Canada my second home" don't seem congruent. Invitation letters are addressed here: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/letter-invitation.html